# What bandwidth is required for broadcasting a live video to say 50000 users

Tags: networking, streaming, broadcast, rtmp

I am assigned on project to live broadcast an event on the internet which may have 50,000 user s. This will be a broadcast so all users will see same live video. My query is what would be my bandwidth requirement in terms of no of users viewing that stream.

1. I am little confused & the reason is does every users need a separate stream of bandwidth in broadcast ?
2. If i would install a server with streaming capability having Bandwidth of 50Mbps would it be enough considering it is a broadcast.
3. Do i necessarily need to have Class C IP to run streaming server on rtmp protocol.
4. Is is possible to achieve this through RTSP. How do services like Google Hangout air work? What protocol is used in Hangout and Youtube when live broadcasts are done.

Kindly suggest me solution especially mention if you have such practical experiance.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer networking

Comment: How sites streaming cricket and football matches work. And as far as i know these site don't have such heavy bandwidth connections and they do have quite good no. of viewers.

Comment: @MikePennington This question isn't purely about the networking, it's about constructing the whole system which requires a lot of software.  I don't think this is off-topic.  It is awfully broad though.

Comment: Brad, I guess I still don't understand how this is related to programming.   His questions have nothing to do with code and everything to do with system / network administration

Comment: I see where you are coming from.  I often err on the side of leaving a question open.  I see no harm in it, especially considering this topic is off-topic for ServerFault since the heart of the question is about what protocols to use and why.  These are StackOverflow questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a ton of bandwidth and resources.

To calculate how much bandwidth you need, you will need to know your average bitrate for the video.  Let's just say that your live video's bitrate is 1 megabit (ignoring overhead, retransmissions, sequences that require more bandwidth, etc.).  Your 50Mbps only covers 50 users.  That's 0.1% of what you require.  You need 1,000 of those connections, to barely handle the load.

If you actually have a live event that 50,000 people will see, you no doubt have sponsors and should be able to afford a proper CDN.  This isn't something you host yourself.  You pay for a CDN so that capacity is available as you need it, and servers are close to your audience.

The best thing to do would be to get a YouTube account with live streaming, and let YouTube pay for the bandwidth.

Now, the protocol you use has nothing to do with what size of IP block you have.  Those are unrelated, separate issues.

RTMP, RTSP, HTTP progressive, etc... if you use a CDN, you get to use all of them with little effort.  You pick a streaming protocol based on device compatibility and capability.

Google Hangout works using WebRTC, which is primarily peer-to-peer.  When you stream them to YouTube, there is a massive CDN that handles distribution in multiple codecs, multiple protocols, and multiple points of presence.

Comment: My confusion was that do we have something say like protocol that can broadcast a single stream like we do in television broadcasts and all users can ride the same stream and let other things such as session, web services, etc be managed by Web server. But your answer and little research gave me quite clear insight. Since the program is educational and we don't have big sponsors so for now possibly youtube would be the need of the hour. My perception and curiosity came to influence me because i thought sites streaming cricket and football matches have lots audience and they do it successfully